# Automatically eval a local script on a specific URI in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to improve an existing website (I have no access to) by using my own javascript.

This means I have to add an < script > to the < head >. I am currently doing this by clicking on a bookmark which has something like this as its target:

```
javascript: if(document.createElement){
    void(head=document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0));
    void(script=document.createElement('script'));
    void(script.src='http://local/script.js');
    void(script.type='text/javascript');
    void(head.appendChild(script));
} // i added some spacer to make it readable
```

This works fine, but since i've got a lot of different scripts it gets complicated to organize them.
I am now looking for a way to automatically insert a defined script-uri if the top.location.href matches a given string.
Is there a way firefox can do something like this - maybe with the help of an add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Userscripts](https://userscripts.org/about/installing) are what you're looking for. Use [Greasemonkey for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to run your own script on specific sites.

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/modules/sdk/page-mod.html uses the add-on sdk, and provides precisely what you're looking for (i.e. an easy way to attach a script to a webpage if it matches a given domain). That gives you the option of making your addon a standalone one easily; moreover, if you were to extend its functionality significantly, the addon sdk would certainly be the way to go!